# Running Hive Queries in Python?

Tags: python, hadoop, hive

I've been stuck on this for a few hours and am having trouble making any progress. I have a remote Hadoop instance with Hue server I've been running Hive queries against. These work fine. I've been hoping to run the queries against hive directly through Python now, but this is where my problems arise. I've tried running things through both [Python Hive Utils](https://github.com/eventbrite/python_hive_utils) and [pyhs2](https://github.com/BradRuderman/pyhs2). The former gives me:

```
thrift.Thrift.TApplicationException: Invalid method name: 'get_database'
```

The latter just times out.

I know the server is using 0.10.0-cdh4.3.0, but I don't know how to tell if it's using HiveServer or HiveServer2.

So, my question is three-fold:

1. How do I know which version of HiveServer is being used?
2. Does that matter in terms of connecting through Python?
3. Why can't I connect?

Answer (score 2):

You can just use ODBC instead.
in phyton :

```
import pyodbc
cnxn = pyodbc.connect("DSN=XXX",autocommit=True)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute("select * from YYY")
```

Where `XXX` is a previously created DSN..
For the drivers go [here](http://www.cloudera.com/content/support/en/downloads/download-components/download-products/downloads-listing/connectors/cloudera-odbc-drivers.html)
When defining the the DSN you have to set the port (default 10000) and whether its HiveServer1 or 2.
To know if its 1 or 2 you need access to the server and check what process listens on that relevant port. (`netstat` will give you the process number and the port and `jps -m` will give you the process number and whether its HiveServer1 or 2)

Comment: Is there a way to extract the hive logs getting generated from this connection?